# Create element if it does not exist in a PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) to build a new xml file.

I need to loop through an array of parent/children and add them to my xml.  If the parent does not exist, I want to create it and then add a child.  If it does exist, I want to add the child to that element.

Essentially, this:

```
$arr = array(
  'fruit' => 'apple',
  'car'   => 'toyota',
  'fruit' => 'kiwi',
  'car'   => 'ford'
)
```

Needs to become this:

```
  <categories>
    <fruit>
      <apple/>
      <kiwi/>
    </fruit>
    <car>
      <toyota/>
      <ford/>
    </car>
  </categories>
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
// create category element
$categories = $dom->createElement('categories');

// add each element to $categories
foreach($arr as $parent => $child){

  // try to find pre-existing parent
  $tmp_parent = $categories->some_function_to_find_child( $parent );

  // ..or create new parent
  if( $tmp_parent == null ) {
    $tmp_parent = $categories->appendElement( $parent );
  } 

  // add child
  $tmp_parent->appendElement( $child );

}

// add $categories to $dom
$dom->appendChild( $categories );
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How do I do this?  The code I added to the bottom is just psudo-code to illustrate my goal.

Comment: @doub1ejack array keys have to be unique. You will have to flip it around or store both values as the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to search for existing element:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// create category element
$categories = $dom->createElement('categories');

// add each element to $categories
foreach ($arr as $parent => $child) {

    // try to find pre-existing parent
    $tmp_parent = $xpath->query($parent, $categories);

    // ..or create new parent
    if ($tmp_parent->length == 0) {
        $categories->appendChild($dom->createElement($parent));
    } else {
        // add child
        $tmp_parent->item(0)->appendChild($dom->createElement($child));
    }
}

// add $categories to $dom
$dom->appendChild($categories);

print_r($dom->saveXML());
```

Comment: Ok, the way this is set up, if the category already exists, the new child will never be added.

Comment: @doub1ejack What do you mean? The code I wrote just shows the basic idea, consider it as a pseudo-code, which you have to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Yup, thanks.  That is what I did and it is working well.  Consider that comment a note for other people in the future.  It looks close enough to real code that people could easily assume it should work as-is.